# Why do I see some edges in object view?

Tags: edges, topology

I'm trying to make table and I can't understand what's happening with my topology. I just see some edges in object mode. I suppose something with normals, but I tried to recalculate outside but without any effect. That's what I'm talking about:
[image]

[image]

Comment: The 'File' link you put under the image doesn't go anywhere. If you want to share your file, do it through https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions on the page.

Comment: Untick `Wireframe` in Overlays > Geometry?

Comment: @JohnEason, sorry, fixed.

Comment: @relaxed it's already unticked - doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure how you created that object, but those lines aren't actually part of the surface of the object! if you go into Edge mode in Edit mode , you can select all those lines across the corner and 'X' - delete them without affecting the rest of the object.

Comment: @JohnEason Well, I just created a |_ -shape object and beveled evere vertical edge. After that I've got strange web around inner corners, so I've fixed it... as I thought.